# iOS5 combine CGAffineTransform with animationImages?

Tags: animation, ios5, uiimageview, uiimage, cgaffinetransform

I'm pretty new to iOS animation and I'm wondering if it's possible to combine an transition between two images along with a translation animation of the UIImageView using CGAffineTransform?

In other words I have two images that I want to animate between, and then I want to apply a simultaneous translation so that the whole thing moves across the page while moving back and forth between the two images.

I know I can apply a [CGAffineTransformConcat](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html) to combine two CGAffineTransforms such as a [CGAffineTransformTranslate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html) and something else.  But I don't see a CGAffineTransform which allows me to transition to another UIImage.

The only way I know to animate between images is to use the UIImageView [animationImages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) array combined with startAnimating.  However, I don't know how to combine this with a translation like so:

```
UIImageView* textView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:bunnyImage.frame]; 

textView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"bunnyclose.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"bunnytalk.png"],
                            nil];

textView.animationDuration = 1.0;
textView.animationRepeatCount = 8;
[textView startAnimating];

[self.view addSubview:textView];
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to my own question, the block animation function [transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionFromView%3atoView%3aduration%3aoptions%3acompletion%3a) as discussed in ["Creating Animated Transitions Between Views"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html) is the best solution that I have come up with yet.  I use this to animate between images and this can be combined with the block animation [animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionFromView%3atoView%3aduration%3aoptions%3acompletion%3a) using CGAffineTransformTranslate or simply by changing the [center](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/center) of the UIImageView as discussed in [Animations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html).

Reworking my original codeblock and adding my translation looks something like this:

```
UIImageView* bunny2View = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:bunny2Image.frame]; 


[UIView 
 transitionFromView:bunny2Image 
 toView:bunny2View 
 duration:10.0 
 options:UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews 
 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
     [UIView 
      animateWithDuration:dur 
      animations:^(void) {
          CGPoint center = bunny2Image.center;
          center.y += deltay;
          bunny2Image.center = center;
          bunny2View.center = center;
      }
      completion:^(BOOL finished) {

          [UIView 
           transitionFromView:bunny2View 
           toView:bunny2Image 
           duration:10.0 
           options:UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews 
           completion:nil];
      }];
 }];
```

Still a work in progress, but this is what I've come up with so far!